# Using SimpleXML to read attributes

Tags: xml, simplexml

I am still trying to get the hang of PHP and XML.
I have a XML that I am going to truncate to save space.
I would like to get the dimension name attribute **display-name** value from each of the records.
I also have to get the **servermanager** status value from each of the records as well.

I was using:

```
$completeurl = "http://website/data.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);
$xml->dimension;

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $servername = $dimensions[$i]->attributes()->display-name;
    $status = $dimensions[$i]->servermanager;
};
```

However, I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in the lines I am trying to assign variables.
```

I am removing all the extra data between the dimension that I don't want to parse. The truncated XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aostats version="0.6" timestamp="2013-02-13 21:16:01 UTC">
    <dimension name="d1" display-name="Atlantean" loadmax="2" locked="0" players="100%">
        <servermanager status="1"/>
        <clientmanager status="0"/>
        <chatserver status="1"/>
    </dimension>
    <dimension name="d2" display-name="Rimor" loadmax="2" locked="0" players="100%">
        <servermanager status="1"/>
        <clientmanager status="0"/>
        <chatserver status="1"/>
    </dimension>
    <dimension name="dt" display-name="Test" loadmax="2" locked="0" players="100%">
        <servermanager status="1"/>
        <clientmanager status="0"/>
    </dimension>
</aostats>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself by experimenting:

```
$completeurl = = "http://website/data.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);
$dimensions  = $xml->dimension;
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
$servername = $dimensions[$i]["display-name"];
$status = $dimensions[$i]->servermanager["status"];
}
```